# Qt application without window title on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5.6

I have an application that I wrote using Qt 5.6.0. It's working fine on my Windows 10 x64. I created a cross-compiler on my Windows 10 host in order to compile code to my Raspberry Pi 1 B+. The cross-compiler is working good but when I execute my application on Raspberry Pi the window's title and all window's buttons (maximize, minimize and close) don't show up. 
I can't move the window or resize it. Does someone have any ideia.

PS: I tried to run my application using all -platform parameters option and it still behaviors the same way.